# Strange number in the footnote before the reference

Tags: footnotes

I am writing a report and when I use the basic footnote command I get a strange 9 before the footnote number and the text. This happens for all the footnotes. I attach the picture in the link.

[image]

I just use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, but the same happens with `\footnote`.

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate-10pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}


\begin{document}

\title{asdfasdf}

\author{
\alignauthor asdfasdf\\
   \affaddr{asdfasdf}\\
   \affaddr{asdfasdf}\\
   \email{\{asdfasdf}
}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsec}
text\footnotemark.
\footnotetext[1]{footnote text \cite{asd} asdf.}
\end{document}
```

I realised that after removing the `\usepackage{setspace}` works again. Files:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/grhmhp0phznco34/trial.zip

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is the example, and I attach both files (the cls file and the trial).

Comment: I get no strange number. Why are you splitting the footnote in the two parts? Just `\footnote` will do, in that case. And you probably don't need the optional argument to `\footnotetext` in any case.

Comment: Works for me even with `\usepackage{setspace}` and I get `^{1} footnote text [?] asdf.` and not `9^{2}text` for your example.

Comment: We are not able to reproduce your problem, so it is hard to know what is causing it. Perhaps you could check your TeX distribution is up-to-date, and add the output of `\listfiles` in case it is caused by differing package versions, but I do not consider it likely. If removing `setspace` resolves things for you, do you really need to keep it?